# Lagrange multiplier - no $g(x,y)$

Tags: calculus, lagrange-multiplier

> Using the method of Lagrange multipliers, find the points on the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 4$ that are furthest from and closest to the point $(1, 1)$.

I don't even know where to start, no obvious $g(x,y)$?

Comment: The constraint is that the point lies on the circle.  The objective is the distance to the fixed point (or the square of that distance, to simplify the computations).  Note:  it should be easy for you to answer these questions geometrically, without any calculus.  Worth doing, if for no other reason than to check the other approach.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Consider minimizing the distance of the point $p=(x,y)$ to the point $p_1=(1,1)$ under the constraint that $p\in \{x,y:x^2+y^2=4\}$. This problem writes:

$$
\min_{p}d(p,p_1)\quad \text{subject to: $p\in \{(x,y):x^2+y^2=4\}$}
$$

where $d(p,p_1)$ is the [euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) between $p$ and $p_1$. Does this help?